# HtmlAgilityPack selecting nodes with end different

Tags: html-agility-pack, nodes, selectnodes

I've this code...

```
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_335784">
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_342222">
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_554213">
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_31226">
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_9442">
```

The question is...

How can i use the selectnodes or other function to select the ID's...

I try -

```
foreach (HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='td_threadtitle_']"))
```

But the numbers in the end are $%@# Everthing...

[]'s

Comment: could you explain a little more your question? what do you want to select? "td_threadtitle_335784", "td_threadtitle_342222",...? or only the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] I want to select only td_threadtitle_

Then i use This...

```
  `("//a[starts-with(@id,'thread_title_')]")`
```

Works Great!

This code i see here too..

Thanks for the